# javascript prototyped inheritance and object properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I'm trying to apply prototyped inheritance to a function in Javascript. It's all pretty plain and even described in [Wikipedia's javascript lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javascript#Inheritance). It works if my properties are simple javascript types:

```
function Person() {
    this.age = 0;
    this.location = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        absolute: false
    };
};

function Employee() {};

Employee.prototype = new Person();
Employee.prototype.celebrate = function () {
    this.age++;
}

var pete = new Employee();
pete.age = 5;
pete.celebrate();
var bob = new Employee();
bob.celebrate();
console.log("bob is " + bob.age + " pete is " + pete.age);
```

With `Employee.prototype = new Person();`, all Person's properties and (prototyped) methods are inherited by Employee, which is fundamental to inheritance.

This works as expected: `bob is 1 pete is 6`

Now I'm starting to fiddle with pete's location (after celebrating)

```
pete.celebrate();
pete.location.absolute=true;
```

Displaying bob.location.absolute shows: `true`, which is contra intuitive (I didn't touch bob's location so I expect it to have the initial value declared in `Person`) and ruins my solution.

In my initial understanding this should have been false. I do realize that I probably should clone the location object from the initial Person, but I'm not sure where or how to do this.
And if there are maybe better techniques for inheritance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you instantiate a new Employee, all properties of Person are copied. As this is a shallow copy, pete and bob share the same location object. For your problem, there does not seems a very good solution. You can either use a framework or do a hack like this:

```
function Employee() { Person.apply(this); };
```

This calls the Person constructor in the context of the this object.

The MDC has more info on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 3):

Don't run the `Person` constructor when inheriting, an `Employee` shouldn't 
even have a `.location` because it's not in `Person.prototype`.

```
function createObject( fn ){
    function f(){}
    f.prototype = fn.prototype;
    return new f;
}
```

Then:

```
Employee.prototype = createObject( Person );
```

This will inherit properly without side effects (running constructor).

You would only run the parent constructor in the child constructor:

```
function Employee() {
Person.apply( this, arguments );
}
```

Comment: What is the upside of using createObject(Person) instead of new Person()? It only adds one layer of prototype indirection.

Comment: @Kosta to avoid side effects from running a constructor when inheriting. Constructors usually have initialization code in them which you don't wanna run when you are not instantiating anything. a `new Employee` will still be `instanceof Person` because both `Person.prototype` and `f.prototype` point to the same object.

Comment: But you are still running the constructor in createObject() (once). Also, you are running the constructor in Employee() (on each instantiation). Could you give an example where createObject() is useful?

Comment: @Kosta No I am not, I am running an empty constructor, hence no side effects. You could also use `.__proto__` or `Object.create` for this but they are not supported in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issue. I ended up using a separate constructor for the internal object.

```
function engine(cc, fuel) {
       this.cc = cc; 
       this.fuel = fuel
}

function car(type, model, cc, fuel) {
       this.type = type; 
       this.model = model;
       this.engine = new engine(cc, fuel);
}


var mycar = new car("sedan", "toyota corolla", 1500, "gas");
console.log(mycar.type);
//sedan
console.log(mycar.engine.cc);
//1500
```

If I had any methods on the prototypes of 'engine' or 'car' constructors, they would still be available. However, I am not deriving the "car" class from the "engine" class in OOP sense. I didn't need to. The "engine" is used as a component of "car".

Meanwhile, for inheritance, I prefer to use the new methods incorporated in ECMAScript 5 which means using Object.create, Object.defineProperties, etc. They are supported even in IE9. Before that I used the same 'apply()' method suggested by Kosta.